# How to wait for animation to finish if it's more than 50% done?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a state machine to control my character's state. The walking state look like this (Some code omitted)

```
// This gets called every frame to check if the state should change
public override void ChangeState()
{
    if (_groundCheck.Check())
    {
        if (_jump) controller.SetState(typeof(JumpState));
        else if (_rb.velocity.x == 0 && _xDirection == 0) controller.SetState(typeof(IdleState));
    }
}

public override void Update()
{
    _animator.MovingAnimation(_groundCheck.Check());
    _animator.CorrectRotation(_xDirection);
}

// This gets called from "controller.SetState()" before changing to the new state
public override void Exit()
{
    controller.Animator.MovingAnimation(false);
}
```

This works just fine. However, when the character stops moving the animation gets interrupted and transitions directly to the idle state. I want this to happen only if the animation is less than halfway done. If it's more than 50% done I want it to finish playing before changing the state.

I know I can check for the current loop progress like this `_animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime % 1 > 0.5f` but I don't know how to suspend the transition until the animation actually finishes. Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to do this in the setup of the AnimationController state transitions.

Comment: @IanPilipski I tried configuring the exit time of the transition but no matter what I set the animation always plays to completition